# Creating POST vars through Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, select, drop-down-menu

I'm not a javascript expert or even an amateur. I've found some script that I'm playing around with and was wondering how I can create a second variable within the code.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#category").change(function(){
            $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#type").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            var id = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
            $.post("select_type.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                $("select#type").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("select#type").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
    </script> 

   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select#model").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#type").change(function(){
            $("select#model").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#model").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            var id = $("select#type option:selected").attr('value');
            $.post("select_model.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                $("select#model").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("select#model").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

In the second piece of code, I would like to get the category id and create another post variable called $_POST[cat_id]. How can I do this again referring to select_type.php in the same piece of javacode?

This is for a 3 piece chained dropdown where..

drop #1 produces drop #2. Drop #1 & #2 together produce drop #3.

All i need to do know is how to add the second variable grabbing it from the first drop down.

Any help is appreciated.

---

EDIT: I tried to add something like this in, but it doesn't work. The 2nd variable needs to come from the initial first select in the dropdown like the select_type.php file or if somehow the initial value can be stored and carried over to help populate the third select.:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select#model").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#type").change(function(){
            $("select#model").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#model").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            var carrier = $("select#type option:selected").attr('value');
            $.post("select_model.php", {carrier:carrier}, function(data){
                $("select#model").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("select#model").html(data);
            });
            var countryid = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
            $.post("select_type.php", {countryid:countryid}, function(data){
                $("select#type").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("select#type").html(data);
            });         
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Any help?

Comment: An exact solution on this is pointless. The code you found is not particularly great looking code. I suggest you start from the basics, that is JavaScript, then jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT ---
I misunderstood your request. You will need to set an event handler on the first dropbox. You will need to do something more like this:

```
$.post("select_model.php", {carrier:carrier}, function(data){
    $("select#model").removeAttr("disabled").html(data);
});
$("select#category").change(function(){
    var countryid = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
    $.post("select_type.php", {countryid:countryid}, function(data){
        $("select#type").removeAttr("disabled").html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't seem to get anything working for me. The value in your code (attr) needs to come from select_type.php. I tried writing something like this, but it didn't work. Any advice on this?

Comment: Revised my solution to match this requirement.

Comment: The alternative to my solution is to use a synchronous post using the jQuery ajax method. See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it.

```
var id = $("select#type option:selected").attr('value');
var categoryID = 34; 
$.post("select_model.php", {id:id, cat_id:categoryID}, function(data){
    $("select#model").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("select#model").html(data);
});
```

And for multiple dropdown please see this : [How to handle multiple select dropdown - JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899137/how-to-handle-multiple-select-dropdown-jquery/11900065#11900065). It is using static content, but I hope you can modify it adding required ajax requests in between.